# Microsoft Graph PowerShell to retrieve group audit log data

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, group, audit-logging

I need a Microsoft Graph PoweShell script that retrieves Azure AD Audit Log data, specifically the date a user was added to an Azure AD group.  I assume this can be accomplished since when exporting the group Audit Log report all the data I want to query with my script exists (Date, Activity, and User Principal Name/Object ID).

I already have the Azure App registration setup with the required API permissions and I assume the PowerShell cmdlet used to query is “Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit” but being somewhat new to MS Graph and PowerShell I do not understand how to Filter or how to include the paramters to retrieve this info.

I tried to execute the Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit cmdlet after connecting to MS Graph which does return data but not what I need since I dont have the proper filters or paramaters as part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

All the supported filter properties are listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

if you want to see all the user group add activities then

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to group'"
```

and then activityDateTime should tell you when it happened.

If you want to limit it to a specific group the options for the Target resource are either the name of the id so

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -filter "targetResources/any(t:t/displayName eq 'nameofgrouphere')"
```

You can join the two with an And operator as well eg

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -filter "(activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to group' and targetResources/any(t:t/displayName eq 'GropuName'))"
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. That works for me except when I try to add the filter for a specific user I get "invalid filter clause".  Running this by itself works:

Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "TargetResources/any(t:t/UserPrincipalName eq '$upn')"

But when I combine with the other two I get the error.  This is what I'm executing: 

Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -filter "(activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to group' and targetResources/any(t:t/displayName eq '$ProjGroupObj)' and TargetResources/any(t:t/UserPrincipalName eq '$upn'))"

Comment: in your example you have a quote in the wrong place after $ProjGroupObj eg it should be Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -filter "(activityDisplayName eq 'Add member to group' and targetResources/any(t:t/displayName eq '$ProjGroupObj') and TargetResources/any(t:t/UserPrincipalName eq '$upn'))"

Comment: Thanks again Glenn.  Fixing the typo results in it no longer displaying the error but it does not return anything.  I guess it's something with the logic but I thought it was the way do "Display the date when the user was added to the group".

Comment: The documentation suggests that UserPrincipalName isn't a filterable property as it isn't listed only id and displayName. It maybe that it works but isn't supported in all types of queries.